# How to get time difference inside window

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table like following. I would like to get duration from `start` to `finish` in each `type`. I can get finish time by agg function `max` in time

```
type event   attribute  time
A    start   start      2019-04-21 23:58:33.0
A    result  process1   2019-04-22 23:58:33.0
A    result  process2   2019-04-23 23:58:33.0
A    result  process3   2019-04-24 23:58:33.0
B    result  process1   2019-04-26 23:58:33.0
B    start   start      2019-04-25 23:58:33.0
B    result  process2   2019-04-27 23:58:33.0
```

I created following queries and joined them.

```
select type,event,attribute,time
from table
where event in ('start')
```

```
select type,event,attribute,max(time) as time
from table
where event in ('result')
group by type,event,attribute
```

```
select tmp2.time - tmp1.time as duration
```

But I guess window function will be useful in this condition.to simplify my query, I'd like to refactor with window function.

Are there good way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: So you need to know the duration of every type? Is it correct to presume the start time is the min value in the group or should it be of event "start" ?

Comment: thank you for comment, start time should be of the event `start` , and my desired result is to get duration of every type.. thanks

Comment: I think @Edouard H. answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the start time as the `min` value of time in the `grouped by type` then you don't need a `window` function, only `agg` functions :

```
SELECT type
     , min(time) AS start
     , max(time) AS finish
  FROM table
 GROUP BY type ;
```

If you consider the start time as the time associated to the start event, and the finish time as the `max` time associated to the result event in the `group by type`, then you need `window` functions :

```
SELECT min(time) FILTER (WHERE event = 'start') AS start
     , max(time) FILTER (WHERE event = 'result') AS finish
  FROM table
 GROUP BY type
```

PS : as stated in the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html), any aggregate function can be used as a window function :

> any built-in or user-defined ordinary aggregate (i.e., not ordered-set
> or hypothetical-set aggregates) can be used as a window function